# Socket.io can connect from remote client but not from localhost / 127.0.0.1

Tags: node.js, websocket, socket.io, localhost

I have 2 process that runs (say, ProcessA and ProcessB), and I want to make both process able to communicate to each other.
ProcessA is an Express web server, while ProcessB is the other.

I'm able to connect to ProcessA's Socket.io from remote client (different network) using external IP + port (http://193.1xx.87.1xx:300xx/).
But I can't connect from ProcessB that runs within same network, I tried both localhost and 127.0.0.1 but still no result

```js
// socket.io-client (socket) variable from ProcessB
Socket {
ids: 0,
acks: {},
receiveBuffer: [],
sendBuffer: [Array],
flags: {},
io: [Manager],
/* The namespace is /api2 */
nsp: '/api2',
connected: false,
disconnected: true,
subs: [Array],
_callbacks: [Object]
}
```

This is what's inside ProcessA's socket.io

```js
var app = require("express")();
var http = require('http').createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http, { path: "/socketio" });
var internal = io.of("/api2");
http.listen(300xx, ()=>{console.log("Online")})

internal.on("connection", async (socket) => {
     console.log(`${socket.request.headers['x-forwarded-for']} connected to internal io`);
// Do stuff from here
// ...
})
```

And from ProcessB's socket.io-client

```js
var socket = require('socket.io-client')('http://localhost/api2', {path: "/socketio"});
socket.on('connect', function(){
     console.log("Connected to Express Web");
//Do stuff from here
//...
});
```

FYI, ProcessA (Web Express) is running behind reverse proxy (Nginx), but I belive this is not the problem.

Things I've tried:

1. Run ProcessB from remote client (still failed to connect)
2. Log every incoming socket connection request (Able to capture incoming connection from 127.0.0.1, but still can't connect)
3. Directly access ProcessA (Nginx port = 80, ProcessA = 30020), web running fine but Socket.io was not able to connect

EDIT: Someone asked for result of "ifconfig -a", so here it is:

```
eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.100.3  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.100.255
        ether dc:a6:32:4f:a0:3f  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 226115  bytes 46904899 (46.9 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 60  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 234239  bytes 89903228 (89.9 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 1042045  bytes 115800804 (115.8 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 1042045  bytes 115800804 (115.8 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

tun0: flags=4305<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,NOARP,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 10.117.202.35  netmask 255.255.254.0  destination 10.117.202.35
        unspec 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  txqueuelen 100  (UNSPEC)
        RX packets 123243  bytes 28872105 (28.8 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 125016  bytes 8806357 (8.8 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 111 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlan0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether dc:a6:32:4f:a0:41  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

EDIT: Content of /etc/hosts

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.1.1   Serevya

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
104.20.26.217  assets.windscribe.com #ws-dns
104.20.26.217  api.windscribe.com #ws-dns
```

Comment: It seems you have no loopback address configured. plz. post results of command "ifconfig -a".

Comment: Done, I've editted the question

Comment: Hi, ok it wasn't that. Can you post content of /etc/hosts too plz ?

Comment: Do you run your application inside containers such as docker, LXC/LXD or any else ?

Comment: no, i didnt use things such as docker or lxc / lxd

Comment: Seems correct too. Perhaps a routing rule. You can check "ip route show table all" it can even be a firewall rule on local machine or virtualized cluster if you are hosting on a cloud.